Rigging is going out of shape on setup
I have been issues trying to setup a rig in Blender 3.0.1. I have followed a tutorial(HERE) multiple times and it has worked, but for this particular character it is giving me issues. Everything is fine until I apply inversekinematics, for some reason the legs attach to the target bone and the leg bones do not react properly in pose mode. When I go into the pose setting and select "rest pose" it looks the way it should. I have no idea why this is not working and would really appreciate any suggestions.
Thank you for the response. I have add the link 


I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

You have reversed the target and the pole target bones, bone 1 should be the pole target, bone 2 should be the target. As soon as you switch to Pose mode, the IK bone will stick to the target, that's why the foot sticks to your current ikTarget.L:


Thank you so much. This solved the problem. I really appreciate the help.
